# Is there a free app like Sublime Text 2 on iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

Is there a free app like Sublime Text 2 on iPad that can read code and have Syntax Highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Textastic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textastic-code-editor-for/id383577124?mt=8).

I've tried many others [Code](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codemate-syntax-highlighter/id680609457?mt=8), [Diet Coda](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/diet-coda/id500906297?mt=8), etc. While they all have some decent features, nothing is quite up to par yet all around in comparison to Textastic in my opinion (especially if you like Sublime Text).

Comment: Dear Sir, I am sorry, it's my bad, I did not make my statements clear. I am looking for a free app.

Comment: Maybe try opening this in Safari for iOS? https://tohtml.com/ Also ☞ https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codeanywhere/id436736239

Answer (score 0):

Best I've come across AND use daily is Koder! Codeanywhere looked the most promising and had the best UI but the worst experience and support (response to an email asking why it constantly crashed whenever I tried to connect via ftp) came after 3 weeks and didn't even try to answer the question. Koder... I'm sure has even worse support but I never had to reach out so Koder wins. I've tried them all as my iPad is all that's left at the moment while I save for a new MacBook pro for my Deving purposes. Love Koder and isn't too far from the slick CodeAnywhere ui but it frickin works. Got a few suggestions as the uploading (copy paste) method is not intuitive at all but the doc has video and if you follow it exactly it works. It's got WebDAV, ftp, Dropbox, syntax highlighting, custom keyboard for commonly used functions and characters and actually substitutes for the lack of a proper file system management tool in iOS. It's like $5 bucks but it but worth it. I can't believe no one mentions it.